# Unable to compile simple TypeScript node-ts example

Tags: node.js, typescript, ts-node

I am trying to learn https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node. I've written two files as a simplistic example. They are both in the same directory, which is currently not in the same folder as package.json

```
/package.json
/src/build-lib/run-ts.js
/src/build-lib/Test.ts
```

run-ts.js

```
require('ts-node').register();
const Test = require('./Test.ts').Test; // Tried with and without .ts extension
const tester = new Test();
tester.log('Message');
```

Test.ts

```
export class Test {
    log(message: string) {
        console.log(`Test ${message}`);
    } 
}
```

I'm running the following script:

```
ts-node src/build-scripts/gen-xml.js
```

And I'm getting the following compilation error

```
/Users/jmendes/gitclient/vcd-ui/content/core/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:319
      throw new TSError(formatDiagnostics(diagnosticList, cwd, ts, lineOffset))
            ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
src/build-scripts/Test.ts (7,36): Parameter 'message' implicitly has an 'any' type. (7006)
    at getOutput (/Users/jmendes/gitclient/vcd-ui/content/core/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:319:17)
    at /Users/jmendes/gitclient/vcd-ui/content/core/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:350:18
```

I expected to see "Test Message" on the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have a *JavaScript* file (run-ts.js) which is itself registering TypeScript to intercept any `require` calls made.

Have you tried running that file with just `node` instead of `ts-node`?

Comment: It does work when I run node. I don't quite understand what the problem was. If you call `ts-node`, all the files have to be TypeScript? By the way, the reason I was using ts-node to run the script was because initially run-ts was a TypeScript file, but I have to import HandleBars which does not provide TS definitions, so I changed it to run-ts.js

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was to remove `ts-node` and `typescript` from `package.json`, then:

```
npm install ts-node --save-dev
npm install -g typescript --save-dev
```